# Redirect 'myapp.com' to 'www.myapp.com' in rails without using htaccess?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, subdomain

Using Morph Labs' Appspace to deploy a site means no automated way to redirect 'myapp.com' to 'www.myapp.com' (and no access to .htacess).

Is there an in-rails way to do this? Would I need a plugin like [subdomain-fu](http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu/tree/master)?

More specifically, I'm trying to do something like:

- 'myapp.com' => 'www.myapp.com'
- 'myapp.com/session/new' => 'www.myapp.com/session/new'

Basically, I always want the 'www' subdomain prepended on every request (because the SSL cert specifically has a common name of 'www.myapp.com').

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Maybe something like this would do the trick:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_uri

  def check_uri
    redirect_to request.protocol + "www." + request.host_with_port + request.request_uri if !/^www/.match(request.host)
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks sweet, I'm gonna give this a try on the next deploy and report back on the results!

Comment: Carson, I apologize for not marking your answer as the answer I accepted previously.

I didn't realize all I had to do was click on the check mark.

Again, my apologies.

Comment: This is a great use case for a Rack middleware though. You can get some ideas from this one: http://coderack.org/users/jtrupiano/entries/37-rackrewrite

Comment: MAKE SURE TO PUT THE CHECK_URI AS THE FIRST BEFORE FILTER.  I have recently run into several very difficult problem to track down in my app, and they all resulted from logged_in checks occuring before the check_uri call.

Comment: hgimenez is absolutely correct that a rack middleware is perfect for this situation. The link he gives returns a 404 now, but the same site has a middleware called "Force Domain" that likely replaced initial middleware hgimenez linked to.

Comment: This is great code but if it's SSL this doesn't prevent the SSL browser warning from appearing.

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 3.2 or 4. You'll need to change `request.request_uri` to `request.fullpath`

Answer (score 8):

Carson's answer works great.

Here's the code to go the other way (www -> no www)

```
before_filter :check_uri

def check_uri
  if /^www/.match(request.host)
    redirect_to request.protocol + request.host_with_port[4..-1] + request.request_uri 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to change Carson's answer to get this to work in Rails 3. I replaced request.uri with request.fullpath:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  Rails.env.production? do
    before_filter :check_url
  end

  def check_url
    redirect_to request.protocol + "www." + request.host_with_port + request.fullpath if !/^www/.match(request.host)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked great for me. I did make one small addition as I only wanted this behavior in my production environment:

```
def check_uri
  redirect_to request.protocol + "www." + request.host_with_port + request.request_uri if !/^www/.match(request.host) if Rails.env == 'production'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is answered, but I thought everyone else should know about the CodeRack: Canonical Host solution. This is really nice as it allows for env specific redirects. http://coderack.org/users/tylerhunt/middlewares/6-canonical-host

Answer (score 0):

Here is a couple of different ways:

```
 head :moved_permanently, :location => ‘http://www.newdomain.com’
```

another:

```
def rails_301
headers["Status"] = "301 Moved Permanently"
redirect_to "http://www.newdomain.com"
end
```

Comment: I just edited my original question to give more detail on what I'm trying to accomplish. 

Does your answer still apply?

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are looking to also force SSL using heroku, this worked well for me, based on [Heroku SSL on root domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701549/heroku-ssl-on-root-domain)

In my DNS settings I set up a URL / Forward record (DNS Simple)

```
URL foo.com     3600        http://www.foo.com
```

The CNAME setup only needs to be setup for WWW

```
CNAME   www.foo.com 3600        providedssslendpoint.herokussl.com
```

I also had to setup and Alias for my root

```
ALIAS   foo.com 3600        providedsslendpoint.herokussl.com
```

Then I decided to simply replace **foo.com** with an env variable `ENV['SITE_HOST']` (where SITE_HOST might equal www.foo.com or test.foo.com) so I can have control via my heroku configuration. That way, I can control what happens in different environments. (for setting up env variables locally see https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)

For example, my test app uses **test.foo.com** as the url it also has its own SSL endpoint so that works fine for me.

```
  before_filter :check_domain

  def check_domain
    if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.testing? and request.host.downcase != ENV['SITE_HOST']
      redirect_to request.protocol + ENV['SITE_HOST'] + request.fullpath, :status => 301
    end
  end
```

From now on, end users will always access www with forced SSL. Old links will suffer a small hang but nothing noticeable.