# Best way to redirect all your pages from www to root domain using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

What's the best way to redirect all your pages from www to root domain using ruby on rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes your host won't let you do redirects, so I think it's ok practice to do it either in your application_controller or middleware. If you're on Rails3, check out this [no-www gem](http://github.com/logicaltext/rack-no-www)

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327122/redirect-myapp-com-to-www-myapp-com-in-rails-without-using-htaccess) has examples of going from www to no-www and from no-www to www.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be in Rails? This is pretty easy to do with Apache, for instance.

http://txt.binnyva.com/2008/09/remove-www-from-url-using-htaccess-in-apache/